# Decrypt aes-128-gcm encoded content with JAVA Cipher using PHP OpenSSL

Tags: java, php, openssl, aes-gcm

I must decrypt some data send to my website, using aes-128-gcm encrypted with JAVA Cipher.

The customer has a provider working with Talend who must send me some information via URL parameter, and I'm stuck trying to decrypt the Data using PHP Openssl. The provider is not really able to tell me how is it working on his side, and is not too sure about the variables used on the generated code (like IV Length for instance).

The encryption method is done on JAVA using a Talend component. The provider send me the Talend generated code as an example.

```
private static String encrypt(String data, String mainKey, int ivLength) throws Exception {
  final byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
  byte[] initializationVector = generateInitializationVector(ivLength);
  final Cipher cipher = getAesGcmCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mainKey, initializationVector);

  final byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
  final byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedData.length + ivLength];
  System.arraycopy(initializationVector, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, ivLength);
  System.arraycopy(encryptedData, 0, encryptedBytes, ivLength, encryptedData.length);

  return BASE64_ENCODER.apply(encryptedBytes);
}

private static String decrypt(String data, String mainKey, int ivLength) throws Exception {
  final byte[] encryptedBytes = BASE64_DECODER.apply(data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));

  final byte[] initializationVector = new byte[ivLength];
  System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, initializationVector, 0, ivLength);

  final Cipher cipher = getAesGcmCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mainKey, initializationVector);
  return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes, ivLength, encryptedBytes.length - ivLength),
      UNICODE_FORMAT);
}
```

He also send me some constants initialised with the class he is using:

```
static final String ALGO = "AES"; //$NON-NLS-1$
static final String GCMALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"; //$NON-NLS-1$
static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8"; //$NON-NLS-1$
static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private static final int DEFAULT_IV_LENGTH = 16;
public static final String NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE = "The parameter should not be null"; //$NON-NLS-1$
public static final String EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE = "String is empty"; //$NON-NLS-1$
private static final String KEY_GEN_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"; //$NON-NLS-1$
static final Random random = new SecureRandom();
static final BASE64Encoder b64Encoder = new DataMasking().new BASE64Encoder();
static final BASE64Decoder b64Dencoder = new DataMasking().new BASE64Decoder();
public static final Function<byte[], String> BASE64_ENCODER = bytes -> Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
public static final Function<byte[], byte[]> BASE64_DECODER = bytes -> Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes);
```

As I understand the Initialisation Vector is placed at the beginning of the string, and I learn that the Tag is automatically placed at the end by the Java Cipher object.

I tried to encrypt and decrypt some content by my own on my PHP side, using [openssl_encrypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-encrypt.php)
 and [openssl_decrypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-decrypt.php), and it is working fine, but I cannot manage to decrypt the data the JAVA application is sending me.

I wonder if it has anything to do with the manipulation of string I have to do on binary data, or if the provider didn't give me all the necessary information I needed.

I also don't know what would be the Tag_length I have to use to decrypt the data.
The provider also tells me the IV_Length is 16 characters long, but when I use openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-gcm'), it propose 12.

Here is the code I'm having for now on my PHP side:

```
/**
 * @param string $str
 *   The URL parameter string
 */
function test_decrypt($str) {
  $key = 'MySuperPassword7';
  $cipher = 'aes-128-gcm';

  $iv_len = 16;
  $tag_length = 16;

  echo $str . '<br>';
  /**
   * Encryption test
   */
//  $tag = ""; 
//  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_len);
//  $enc_str = openssl_encrypt('Test of data to send', $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $tag, "", $tag_length);
//  $encrypt = base64_encode($iv.$enc_str.$tag);

//  echo $key . '::' . $iv . '::' . $tag . '<br>';
//  echo '$enc_str<pre>';
//  var_dump($enc_str);
//  echo '</pre>';
//  echo '$encrypt<pre>';
//  var_dump($encrypt);
//  echo '</pre>';

  /**
   * Decryption part
   */
  $encrypt = base64_decode($str);
  $iv = substr($encrypt, 0, $iv_len);
  $tag = substr($encrypt, - $tag_length);
  $ciphertext = substr($encrypt, $iv_len, -$tag_length);

  $uncrypt = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv, $tag);//OPENSSL_RAW_DATA + OPENSSL_NO_PADDING
  echo $iv_len . '::' . $tag_length . '<br>';
  echo $key . '::' . $iv . '::' . $tag . '<br>';
  echo '$encrypt<pre>';
  var_dump($encrypt);
  echo '</pre>';
  echo '$ciphertext<pre>';
  var_dump($ciphertext);
  echo '</pre>';
  echo '$uncrypt<pre>';
  var_dump($uncrypt);
  echo '</pre>';
  exit;
}
```

I also tried to use online tools to decrypt the data the Java app is sending me, but I couldn't find anything working for so far.

**Edit**

As asked by @JohnConde in the comment, I can share the encrypted string and key I'm currently trying to decrypt.
We decided to test with the same data as the answer of Michael Fehr :

- Key : '1234567890123456'
- Plain text : "Secret data for TytooF"
- Encrypted text : VODKjhFETSxMcaa7x/LIOYCfmqD1iWSCuxX80reQ1KoFhmU8/A5AlH0Pg/ZoK1eNSdhBpUed

The length is the same as the encrypted one of the answer (P8kU/Gf27LU9qgmLpA8gpfHmdVuW5cC7XeKVIgmb3rgGzyjG0YHX5P/cFfRRoZpUxxTEKzj8).

As before, I'm not able to decrypt the data...

Here is the full code of the Talend component:

```
// ============================================================================
//
// Copyright (C) 2006-2019 Talend Inc. - www.talend.com
//
// This source code is available under agreement available at
// %InstallDIR%\features\org.talend.rcp.branding.%PRODUCTNAME%\%PRODUCTNAME%license.txt
//
// You should have received a copy of the agreement
// along with this program; if not, write to Talend SA
// 9 rue Pages 92150 Suresnes, France
//
// ============================================================================

package routines;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PushbackInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


/**
 * created by talend on 2016-04-08 Detailled comment.
 *
 */
public class DataMasking {

    static final String ALGO = "AES"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    static final String GCMALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    static final String DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DES"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final int DEFAULT_IV_LENGTH = 16;

    public static final String NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE = "The parameter should not be null"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    public static final String EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE = "String is empty"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static final String KEY_GEN_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    static final Random random = new SecureRandom();

    static final BASE64Encoder b64Encoder = new DataMasking().new BASE64Encoder();

    static final BASE64Decoder b64Dencoder = new DataMasking().new BASE64Decoder();

    public static final Function<byte[], String> BASE64_ENCODER = bytes -> Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);

    public static final Function<byte[], byte[]> BASE64_DECODER = bytes -> Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes);

    public static class DataMaskingRoutineException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8622896150657449668L;

        public DataMaskingRoutineException() {
            super();
        }

        public DataMaskingRoutineException(String s) {
            super(s);
        }

        public DataMaskingRoutineException(String s, Object o) {
            super(s);
            System.out.println(o);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Encrypt String: Encrypts a string using AES 128 .
     * warning: this is not considered a secure function.
     *
     *
     * {talendTypes} String
     *
     * {Category} Data Masking
     *
     * {param} String("foo") encryptString: The string to be encrypted.
     * 
     * {param} byte[](new byte[] { 'T', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'd', 's', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' })
     * keyValue: the
     * key material of the secret key. The contents of the array are copied to protect against subsequent modification.
     * 
     * {example} encryptAES("foo", new byte[] { 'T', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'd', 's', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' })
     * result is UQ0VJZq5ymFkMYQeDrPi0A==
     *
     * @deprecated use {@link #encryptAESGCM(String, String, int)} instead of it
     * 
     */

    @Deprecated
    public static String encryptAES(String encryptString, byte[] keyValue) {

        if (encryptString == null || keyValue == null) {
            return NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }
        if (encryptString.length() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }
        try {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encVal = cipher.doFinal(encryptString.getBytes());
            String encryptedValue = b64Encoder.encode(encVal);
            return encryptedValue;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataMaskingRoutineException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Encrypt String: Encrypts a string using AES GCM 128 .
     * 
     * {talendTypes} String
     * 
     * {Category} Data Masking
     * 
     * {param} String("foo") encryptString: The string to be encrypted.
     * 
     * {param} String("TalendMainKey123") the main key used to encrypt the data.
     * 
     * {example} encryptAESGCM("foo","TalendMainKey123") result could be
     * +ngs4RohAx8OvInmioRwRYS0pymcNkQJCKqsdUPZqUZppN4= (but it should change from an execution to another).
     * 
     */

    public static String encryptAESGCM(String encryptString, String mainKey) {

        return encryptAESGCM(encryptString, mainKey, DEFAULT_IV_LENGTH);
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt String: Encrypts a string using AES GCM 128 .
     * 
     * {talendTypes} String
     * 
     * {Category} Data Masking
     * 
     * {param} String("foo") encryptString: The string to be encrypted.
     * 
     * {param} String("TalendMainKey123") the main key used to encrypt the data.
     * 
     * {param} int the length of initializationVector. must be one of 12/13/14/15/16.
     * 
     * {example} encryptAESGCM("foo","TalendMainKey123",16) result could be
     * +ngs4RohAx8OvInmioRwRYS0pymcNkQJCKqsdUPZqUZppN4= (but it should change from an execution to another).
     * 
     */

    public static String encryptAESGCM(String encryptString, String mainKey, int ivLength) {

        if (encryptString == null || mainKey == null) {
            return NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }

        if (encryptString.length() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }

        try {
            return encrypt(encryptString, mainKey, ivLength);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataMaskingRoutineException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }



    /**
     * decrypt String: Decrypts a string using AES 128.
     * warning: this is not considered a secure function.
     *
     *
     * {talendTypes} String
     *
     * {Category} Data Masking
     *
     * {param} String("UQ0VJZq5ymFkMYQeDrPi0A==") encryptedString: The string to be decrypted.
     *
     * {param} byte[](new byte[] { 'T', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'd', 's', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' })
     * keyValue: the key material of the secret key. The contents of the array are copied to protect against subsequent
     * modification.
     * 
     * {example} decryptAES("UQ0VJZq5ymFkMYQeDrPi0A==",new byte[] { 'T', 'a', 'l', 'e', 'n', 'd', 's', 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' })
     * result is "foo"
     * 
     * @deprecated use {@link #decryptAESGCM(String, String, int)} instead of it
     * 
     */

    @Deprecated
    public static String decryptAES(String encryptedString, byte[] keyValue) {

        if (encryptedString == null || keyValue == null) {
            return NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }

        if (encryptedString.length() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }
        try {
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] decordedValue = b64Dencoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
            byte[] decValue = cipher.doFinal(decordedValue);
            String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
            return decryptedValue;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataMaskingRoutineException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * decrypt String: Decrypts a string using AES GCM 128.
     * 
     * {talendTypes} String
     * 
     * {Category} Data Masking
     * 
     * {param} String("+ngs4RohAx8OvInmioRwRYS0pymcNkQJCKqsdUPZqUZppN4=") encryptedString: The string to be decrypted.
     * 
     * {param} String("TalendMainKey123") the main key used to decrypt the data.
     * 
     * {param} int the length of initializationVector. must be one of 12/13/14/15/16.
     * 
     * {example} decryptAESGCM("+ngs4RohAx8OvInmioRwRYS0pymcNkQJCKqsdUPZqUZppN4=","TalendMainKey123",16) result
     * is "foo"
     * 
     */

    public static String decryptAESGCM(String encryptedString, String mainKey, int ivLength) {

        if (encryptedString == null || mainKey == null) {
            return NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }

        if (encryptedString.length() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }

        try {
            return decrypt(encryptedString, mainKey, ivLength);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataMaskingRoutineException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * decrypt String: Decrypts a string using AES GCM 128.
     * 
     * {talendTypes} String
     * 
     * {Category} Data Masking
     * 
     * {param} String("+ngs4RohAx8OvInmioRwRYS0pymcNkQJCKqsdUPZqUZppN4=") encryptedString: The string to be decrypted.
     * 
     * {param} String("TalendMainKey123") the main key used to decrypt the data.
     * 
     * {example} decryptAESGCM("+ngs4RohAx8OvInmioRwRYS0pymcNkQJCKqsdUPZqUZppN4=","TalendMainKey123") result
     * is "foo"
     * 
     */

    public static String decryptAESGCM(String encryptedString, String mainKey) {

        return decryptAESGCM(encryptedString, mainKey, DEFAULT_IV_LENGTH);
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt String: Encrypts a string using DES .
     * warning: this is not considered a secure function.
     *
     *
     * {talendTypes} String
     *
     * {Category} Data Masking
     *
     * {param} String("foo") unencryptedString: The string to be encrypted.
     *
     * {param} String("ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey") myEncryptionKey: the string with the DES key material.
     *
     * {example} encryptDES("foo") result is DmNj+x2LUXA=
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */

    public static String encryptDES(String unencryptedString, String myEncryptionKey) {

        if (unencryptedString == null || myEncryptionKey == null) {
            return NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }
        if (unencryptedString.length() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }
        try {
            String encryptedString = null;

            String myEncryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
            byte[] keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            KeySpec myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
            SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
            Cipher encipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
            SecretKey key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);

            encipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = encipher.doFinal(plainText);
            encryptedString = b64Encoder.encode(encryptedText);

            return encryptedString;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataMaskingRoutineException(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /**
     * Decrypt String: Decrypts a string using DES .
     * warning: this is not considered a secure function.
     *
     *
     * {talendTypes} String
     *
     * {Category} Data Masking
     *
     * {param} String("DmNj+x2LUXA=") encryptedString: the string with the DES key material.
     *
     * {param} String("ThisIsSecretEncryptionKey") myDecryptionKey: The string to be encrypted.
     *
     * {example} decryptDES("DmNj+x2LUXA=") result is "foo"
     *
     */

    public static String decryptDES(String encryptedString, String myDecryptionKey) {

        if (encryptedString == null || myDecryptionKey == null) {
            return NULL_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }

        if (encryptedString.length() == 0) {
            return EMPTY_PARAMETER_MESSAGE;
        }
        try {
            String decryptedText = null;

            String myDecryptionScheme = DES_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;

            byte[] keyAsBytes = myDecryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);

            KeySpec myKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(keyAsBytes);
            Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance(myDecryptionScheme);
            SecretKeyFactory mySecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myDecryptionScheme);
            SecretKey key = mySecretKeyFactory.generateSecret(myKeySpec);

            decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encryptedText = b64Dencoder.decodeBuffer(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(encryptedText);

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte element : plainText) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) element);
            }
            decryptedText = stringBuilder.toString();
            return decryptedText;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DataMaskingRoutineException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }


    /**
     * This method generates a secret Key using the key-stretching algorithm PBKDF2 of
     * <a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html">javax.crypto</a>.
     * It is basically a hashing algorithm slow by design, in order to increase the time
     * required for an attacker to try a lot of passwords in a bruteforce attack.
     * <br>
     * About the salt :
     * <ul>
     * <li>The salt is not secret, the use of Random is not critical and ensure determinism.</li>
     * <li>The salt is important to avoid rainbow table attacks.</li>
     * <li>The salt should be generated with SecureRandom() in case the passwords are stored.</li>
     * <li>In that case the salt should be stored in plaintext next to the password and a unique user identifier.</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param password a password given as a {@code String}.
     * @param keyLength key length to generate
     * @return a {@code SecretKey} securely generated.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     */
    private static byte[] generateSecretKeyFromPassword(String password, int keyLength)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] salt = new byte[keyLength];
        new Random(password.hashCode()).nextBytes(salt);
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_GEN_ALGO);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, keyLength << 3);
        return factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    }

    private static String encrypt(String data, String mainKey, int ivLength) throws Exception {
        final byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] initializationVector = generateInitializationVector(ivLength);
        final Cipher cipher = getAesGcmCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mainKey, initializationVector);

        final byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
        final byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedData.length + ivLength];
        System.arraycopy(initializationVector, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, ivLength);
        System.arraycopy(encryptedData, 0, encryptedBytes, ivLength, encryptedData.length);

        return BASE64_ENCODER.apply(encryptedBytes);
    }


    private static String decrypt(String data, String mainKey, int ivLength) throws Exception {
        final byte[] encryptedBytes = BASE64_DECODER.apply(data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));

        final byte[] initializationVector = new byte[ivLength];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, initializationVector, 0, ivLength);

        final Cipher cipher = getAesGcmCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mainKey, initializationVector);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes, ivLength, encryptedBytes.length - ivLength),
                UNICODE_FORMAT);
    }

}
```

** EDIT 2 **

After debugging for some times with the provider, we finally decided to use the code provided by Michael Fehr.

What I understood from the code of the component, is that the difference is in the way the main key is used. But I'm not a Java developer, and maybe I misunderstood something.

Just in case it can help someone, here is the additional Java code missing for the IV generation, and the Secret key generation.

```java
private static Cipher getAesGcmCipher(int encryptMode, String mainKey, byte[] initializationVector)
            throws Exception {
    int ivLength = initializationVector.length;
    if (Stream.of(12, 13, 14, 15, 16).noneMatch(i -> i == ivLength)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid IV length"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(GCMALGO);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(generateSecretKeyFromPassword(mainKey, mainKey.length()), ALGO);
    final GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(ivLength * 8, initializationVector);
    cipher.init(encryptMode, key, spec);
    return cipher;
}



private static byte[] generateSecretKeyFromPassword(String password, int keyLength)
          throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
      byte[] salt = new byte[keyLength];
      new Random(password.hashCode()).nextBytes(salt);
      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_GEN_ALGO);
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536, keyLength << 3);
      return factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
}
```

Comment: You need to post the encrypted text, IV, and tag generated by your Java code

Comment: @JohnConde, I can post the encrypted text the provider send me for test, with the key he is currently using. But for the IV and TAG, I have no clue, as I tell before the Java code is automatically generated by the Talend solution component, and the provider is not a developer.
I just ask him to send me the full Java Class generated, to be able to understand better what is happening. I'll see with him if I can share the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I setup your code in Java and made an encryption with a (fixed) key and an random initialization vector:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Random;

public class SO_Main_Final {

    static final String ALGO = "AES"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    static final String GCMALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    static final Random random = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129604/decrypt-aes-128-gcm-encoded-content-with-java-cipher-using-php-openssl");
        String myData = "Secret data for TytooF";
        String myKey = "1234567890123456";
        String encryptString = encrypt(myData, myKey, 16);
        String decryptString = decrypt(encryptString, myKey, 16);
        System.out.println("encryptString:         " + encryptString);
        System.out.println("decryptString:         " + decryptString);

    }

    private static String encrypt(String data, String mainKey, int ivLength) throws Exception {
        final byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        // byte[] initializationVector = generateInitializationVector(ivLength);
        byte[] initializationVector = new byte[ivLength];
        random.nextBytes(initializationVector);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(mainKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT), ALGO);
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, initializationVector);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(GCMALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        final byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
        final byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[encryptedData.length + ivLength];
        System.arraycopy(initializationVector, 0, encryptedBytes, 0, ivLength);
        System.arraycopy(encryptedData, 0, encryptedBytes, ivLength, encryptedData.length);
        System.out.println("data [String]        : " + data);
        System.out.println("data           length: " + dataBytes.length
                + " data: " + bytesToHex(dataBytes));
        System.out.println("mainKey        length: " + mainKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT).length
                + " data: " + bytesToHex(mainKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT)));
        System.out.println("initvector     length: " + initializationVector.length
                + " data: " + bytesToHex(initializationVector));
        System.out.println("encryptedBytes length: " + encryptedBytes.length
                + " data: " + bytesToHex(encryptedBytes));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
    }

    private static String decrypt(String data, String mainKey, int ivLength) throws Exception {
        final byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
        final byte[] initializationVector = new byte[ivLength];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, initializationVector, 0, ivLength);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(mainKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT), ALGO);
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, initializationVector);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(GCMALGO);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes, ivLength, encryptedBytes.length - ivLength),
                UNICODE_FORMAT);
    }

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((b & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

In the end I got this result - the "encryptString" needs to get transfered to your website:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129604/decrypt-aes-128-gcm-encoded-content-with-java-cipher-using-php-openssl
data [String]        : Secret data for TytooF
data           length: 22 data: 536563726574206461746120666f72205479746f6f46
mainKey        length: 16 data: 31323334353637383930313233343536
initvector     length: 16 data: 3fc914fc67f6ecb53daa098ba40f20a5
encryptedBytes length: 54 data: 3fc914fc67f6ecb53daa098ba40f20a5f1e6755b96e5c0bb5de29522099bdeb806cf28c6d181d7e4ffdc15f451a19a54c714c42b38fc
encryptString:         P8kU/Gf27LU9qgmLpA8gpfHmdVuW5cC7XeKVIgmb3rgGzyjG0YHX5P/cFfRRoZpUxxTEKzj8
decryptString:         Secret data for TytooF
```

On webserver/PHP-side I slightly modified your code (the "main change" was the change on the line openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, **true**, $iv, $tag) because we do not present Base64-encoded data to the decrypt
method as this is done some codelines before ($encrypt = base64_decode($str).

Here is the PHP-code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @param string $str
 *   The URL parameter string
 */
function test_decrypt($str)
{
    $key = '1234567890123456';
    $cipher = 'aes-128-gcm';
    $iv_len = 16;
    $tag_length = 16;
    echo $str . '<br>';
    /**
     * Decryption part
     */
    $encrypt = base64_decode($str);
    $iv = substr($encrypt, 0, $iv_len);
    $tag = substr($encrypt, -$tag_length);
    $ciphertext = substr($encrypt, $iv_len, -$tag_length);
    echo "" . "\n";
    $value = unpack('H*', $iv);
    echo '<br>iv:' . $value[1];
    echo "" . "\n";
    $value = unpack('H*', $ciphertext);
    echo '<br>ciphertext:' . $value[1];
    echo "" . "\n";
    $value = unpack('H*', $tag);
    echo '<br>tag:' . $value[1];
    echo "<br>" . "\n";
    $uncrypt = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, true, $iv, $tag);//OPENSSL_RAW_DATA + OPENSSL_NO_PADDING
    echo '<br>DecryptedString: ' . $uncrypt . "\n";
    $value = unpack('H*', $uncrypt);
    echo '<br>DecryptedString [byte[]]:' . $value[1];
    exit;
}

echo '<b>Output for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129604/decrypt-aes-128-gcm-encoded-content-with-java-cipher-using-php-openssl</b><br>' . "\n";
echo '' . "\n";
echo 'Start decryption' . "\n";
$receivedData = "P8kU/Gf27LU9qgmLpA8gpfHmdVuW5cC7XeKVIgmb3rgGzyjG0YHX5P/cFfRRoZpUxxTEKzj8";
test_decrypt($receivedData);
?>
```

This is the decryption output on the webserver:

```
Output for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129604/decrypt-aes-128-gcm-encoded-content-with-java-cipher-using-php-openssl
Start decryption P8kU/Gf27LU9qgmLpA8gpfHmdVuW5cC7XeKVIgmb3rgGzyjG0YHX5P/cFfRRoZpUxxTEKzj8

iv:3fc914fc67f6ecb53daa098ba40f20a5
ciphertext:f1e6755b96e5c0bb5de29522099bdeb806cf28c6d181
tag:d7e4ffdc15f451a19a54c714c42b38fc

DecryptedString: Secret data for TytooF
DecryptedString [byte[]]:536563726574206461746120666f72205479746f6f46
```

**Edit Oct. 10th 2021:** The code above is using an IV/nonce with a length of 16 bytes but the **recommended IV/nonce length is 12**.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Fehr for this answer, As I understand I had to use the constant OPENSSL_RAW_DATA for openssl_decrypt. I tested this earlier with the data the provider send me, but cannot manage to decrypt it.
But with this change, I was able to decrypt your crypted string with the same Key. I then now look for the changes you made on the Java code, to see if the provider is able to replicate it.
As I tell before, he is not really a developer, more an advance user of Talend solution.
I was expecting to be able to adjust my PHP code to decrypt his part. But I think you have the good answer.

Comment: My pleasure. On Java-side I did not really "change" the code but make it usable for my testing, e.g. your provider didn't provide the source for "generateInitializationVector" so I needed to build my own vector. Same with "getAesGcmCipher" so I setup my own directly in "Encrypt" and "Decrypt". One last comment on a missing but important CONSTANT - it's the "GCM Tag len" (not to be confused with INITVECTOR_LENGTH). Usually this tag is 96 bit (12 byte) long but in your PHP-code you set the $tag_length = 16 (128 Bit).

Comment: .. Therefore I fixed the length in GCMParameterSpec(128, initializationVector) to 128 as well. If you cannot decrypt a message from Talend with the PHP-code you may change the $tag_length = 12 or whatever Talend is using as taglen on Java-side. Please mark the answer as "solved" when it meets your expectation, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I also tested a TAG length of 12, and an IV length of 12 too. But nothing append.
I ask him the full JAVA Class code, to be able to share it or understand the trouble.
I also ask him to test his code with the same key and clear text as in your example, it will hopefully help me to understand where is the trouble. I edit my post when I have it.

Comment: I just add the full Java code of the component and an example of encryption of the same data and key as your example...
Thanks for your time.

Comment: We finally decided to use the Java code you provided, easier than the one provided by Talend, and everything is now going fine. Thanks for your help. What we find is that Talend use a modified version of the provided key, that make me unable to use it the same way. But I'll put the code in case it can help someone.

Comment: Actually the _recommended_ and IME usual tag length for AES-GCM is 128bits/16bytes, as this OP apparently had. It is the _IV_ aka _nonce_ length that is recommended to be 96bits/12bytes for GCM. Also, why `"\xA"` for newline instead of the conventional, shorter, and easier to read `"\n"`?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: I added a notice regarding the IV/nonce tag length, thanks for that. The OP used this length in his original code "private static final int DEFAULT_IV_LENGTH = 16", so I used this length. And yes, the newline "\xA" is very old :-)